# All combinations of all elements of a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, combinations

So I have matrix `A`

```
A = [[0,0,1,-1] 
     [0,0,1,-1]
     [0,0,1,-1]
     [0,0,1,-1]]
```

And I want to have all the possible combinations with these elements. This means that rows can change between them and columns as well. In this situation, I would expect a `4^4 = 256` possibilities. I have tried:

```
combs = np.array(list(itertools.product(*A)))
```

It does creates me, my desire to output a matrix of `(256,4)`, but all the rows are equal. This means that I get vector `[0,0,1,-1]`, `256` times.

Here is an example:

```
output = [[0,0,0,0]
          [0,0,0,1]
          [0,0,1,1]
          [0,1,1,1]
          [1,1,1,1]
          [-1,1,1,-1]
          [-1,-1,-1,-1]
             ....
          [0,-1,0,-1]
```

Another example, if

```
A = [[1,2,3] 
     [4,5,6]
     [7,8,9]]
```

The output should be all the possible combinations of arrays that the matrix can form

```
Combs =[[1,1,1] 
        [1,1,2]
        [1,1,3]
        [1,1,...9]
        [2,1,1]
        [2,2,1]
        [1,2,1]
```

Another example would be:
I have the vector layers

```
layers = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And then I have vector angle

```
angle = [0,90,45,-45]
```

each layer can have one of the angles, so I create a matrix A

```
A = [[0,90,45,-45]
     [0,90,45,-45]
     [0,90,45,-45]
     [0,90,45,-45]
     [0,90,45,-45]]
```

Great, but now I want to know all possible combinations that layers can have. For example, layer 1 can have an angle of 0º, layer 2 an angle of 90º, layer 3 an angle of 0º, layer 4 an angle of 45º and layer 5 and an angle of 0º. This creates the array

```
Comb = [0,90,0,45,0]
```

So all the combinations would be in a matrix

```
Comb = [[0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,90]
        [0,0,0,90,90]
        [0,0,90,90,90] 
        [0,90,90,90,90] 
        [90,90,90,90,90] 
             ...
        [0,45,45,45,45]
        [0,45,90,-45,90]]
```

How can I generalize this process for bigger matrices.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe your `A` has identical rows already?

Comment: What's `angle_`?

Comment: @richardec I have edited the post. It is one of the array that creates my matrix A.

Comment: So what's your expected output? By running your code, I'm getting an array of shape `(4, 1, 4)`

Comment: I expect and array of all the possible rows the matrix can create:
[0,0,1,-1] 
[0,1,1,-1] 
[1,0,1,-1]
[0,0,0,0]

Comment: @PedroBrandão. Can you please list those possibilities for people that do not have the same expectations you do? Your prose and code don't match unambiguously.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, I have added!

Comment: Is it me or it's still not obvious what the output should be ;/ Could you show output for A = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] ?

Comment: Okay I have added two new examples of outputs. I think it's clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's OK to use `np.array` in conjunction with `list`(*iterable*), especially in your case where *iterable* is `itertools.product(*A)`. However, this can be optimised since you know the shape of array of your output.

There are many ways to perform `product` so I'll just put my list:

**Methods of Cartesian Product**

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

def numpy_product_itertools(arr):
    return np.array(list(itertools.product(*arr)))

def numpy_product_fromiter(arr):
    dt = np.dtype([('', np.intp)]*len(arr)) #or np.dtype(','.join('i'*len(arr)))
    indices = np.fromiter(itertools.product(*arr), dt)
    return indices.view(np.intp).reshape(-1, len(arr))

def numpy_product_meshgrid(arr):
    return np.stack(np.meshgrid(*arr), axis=-1).reshape(-1, len(arr))

def numpy_product_broadcast(arr): #a little bit different type of output
    items = [np.array(item) for item in arr]
    idx = np.where(np.eye(len(arr)), Ellipsis, None)
    out = [x[tuple(i)] for x,i in zip(items, idx)]
    return list(np.broadcast(*out))
```

**Example of usage**

```
A = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [7]]
numpy_product_itertools(A)
numpy_product_fromiter(A)
numpy_product_meshgrid(A)
numpy_product_broadcast(A)
```

**Comparison of performance**

```
import benchit
benchit.setparams(rep=1)
%matplotlib inline
sizes = [3,4,5,6,7]
N = sizes[-1]
arr = [np.arange(0,100,10).tolist()] * N
fns = [numpy_product_itertools, numpy_product_fromiter, numpy_product_meshgrid, numpy_product_broadcast]
in_ = {s: (arr[:s],) for s in sizes}
t = benchit.timings(fns, in_, multivar=True, input_name='Cartesian product of N arrays of length=10')
t.plot(logx=False, figsize=(12, 6), fontsize=14)
```

[image]

Note that `numba` beats majority of these algorithms although it's not included.