# Why is numpy cartesian product slower than pure python version?

Tags: python, numpy, performance

#### Input

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

a = np.array([ 1,  6,  7,  8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 23, 24, 26, 28, 29, 33,
       34, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 52, 54, 58, 60, 61, 65, 70, 75]).astype(np.uint8)
b = np.array([ 2,  3,  4, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20, 22, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 34, 36, 37,
       38, 39, 40, 41, 46, 48, 49, 50, 52, 53, 55, 56, 57, 59, 60, 63, 66,
       67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 74]).astype(np.uint8)
c = np.array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
       68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75]).astype(np.uint8)
```

I would like to get the Cartesian product of the 3 arrays but I do not want any duplicate elements in one row `[1, 2, 1]` would not be valid and only one of these two would be valid `[10, 14, 0]` or `[14, 10, 0]` since 10 and 14 are both in `a` and `b`.

#### Python only

```
def no_numpy():
    combos = {tuple(set(i)): i for i in itertools.product(a, b, c)}
    combos = [val for key, val in combos.items() if len(key) == 3]
%timeit no_numpy() # 32.5 ms ± 508 µs per loop
```

#### Numpy

```
# Solution from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/18158000)
def cartesian_product(*arrays):
    broadcastable = np.ix_(*arrays)
    broadcasted = np.broadcast_arrays(*broadcastable)
    rows, cols = np.prod(broadcasted[0].shape), len(broadcasted)
    dtype = np.result_type(*arrays)

    out = np.empty(rows * cols, dtype=dtype)
    start, end = 0, rows
    for a in broadcasted:
        out[start:end] = a.reshape(-1)
        start, end = end, end + rows
    return out.reshape(cols, rows).T

def numpy():
    combos = {tuple(set(i)): i for i in cartesian_product(*[a, b, c])}
    combos = [val for key, val in combos.items() if len(key) == 3]
%timeit numpy() # 96.2 ms ± 136 µs per loop
```

My guess is in the numpy version converting the `np.array` to a set is why it is much slower but when comparing strictly getting the initial products `cartesian_product` is much faster than `itertools.product`.

Can the numpy version be modified in anyway to outperform the pure python solution or is there another solution that outperforms both?

Comment: Do those two functions actually return the same thing?

Comment: The same output but different types, the type of the python version returns a `list` of `tuples`, the numpy version returns a `list` of `numpy.ndarray` @TimRoberts

Comment: Aside from the efficiency problems, you've got a correctness problem. `tuple(set(i))` is not a safe key for your use case. There is no guarantee that equal sets will convert to equal tuples. Also, you want to exclude rows like `[1, 2, 1]`, but nothing in your code does that.

Comment: Sorry I was missing `if len(key) == 3` I updated the code, this should exclude rows like `[1, 2, 1]` @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by `There is no guarantee that equal sets will convert to equal tuples` @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: `len(no_numpy())` gives `59825` and `len(cartesian_product(a, b, c))` gives `100320`. Thus the results are not equivalent. Did I miss something?

Comment: @radio23: [This](https://ideone.com/83FfNz) can happen.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: You need to call `numpy()` to do the filtering.

Comment: I was missing `if len(key) == 3` in both examples @JérômeRichard the lengths should both equal `59825` now

Comment: `cartesian_product(a, b, c).tolist()` speeds up the numpy method a lot.  In my timings `cartesian_product` is faster than `list(itertools...)`.  But iteration on a (n,3) array is slower than iteration on the equivalent list of tuples.  `set` on an array might also be slower, though I haven't timed that.

Comment: I think using `tuple(sorted(set(i)))` is sufficient to solve the problem pointed out by @user2357112supportsMonica. It is more compliant with the definition of your problem. Note the number of item significantly decrease with that (it goes down to `50014`)

Comment: @JérômeRichard or, if you don't care about the order, use a `frozenset`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) of `frozenset` does not seem to guarantee the order unlike `dict` (which guarantee an order that the OP does not want). In fact the documentation of `frozenset` states "*sets do not record element position or order of insertion*". Thus, tuples of the temporary `dict` will not be fully filtered regarding the problem description.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: juanpa.arrivillaga means using a frozenset as a key directly, with no conversion to tuple. The lack of order doesn't matter then.

Comment: @radio23 Of course `numpy` can outperform `itertools.product` and it looks like it's much more simple than your attempt. Take a look at my [runtime comparisons of distinct approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70479823/3044825) to solve this problem in `numpy`.

Comment: Unfortunately, those solutions do not solve the problem of "I do not want any duplicate elements in one row `[1, 2, 1]` would not be valid and only one of these two would be valid `[10, 14, 0]` or `[14, 10, 0]` since 10 and 14 are both in `a` and`b`" @mathfux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why current implementations are slow

While the first solution is faster than the second one, it is quite inefficient since it creates a lot of temporary CPython objects (at least 6 per item of `itertools.product`). **Creating a lot of objects is expensive because they are dynamically allocated and reference-counted** by CPython. The Numpy function `cartesian_product` is pretty fast but the iteration over the resulting array is very slow because it creates a lot of Numpy views and operates on `numpy.uint8` instead of CPython `int`. **Numpy types and functions introduce a huge overhead for very small arrays**.

Numpy can be used to speed up this operation as shown by @AlainT but this is not trivial to do and Numpy does not shine to solve such problems.

---

### How to improve performance

One solution is to use **Numba** to do the job yourself more efficiently and let the Numba's *JIT compiler* optimizes loops. You can use 3 nested loops to efficiently generate the value of the Cartesian product and filter items. A dictionary can be used to track already seen values. The tuple of 3 items can be **packed** into one integer so to reduce the memory footprint and improve performance (so the dictionary can better fit in CPU caches and avoid the creation of slow tuple objects).

Here is the resulting code:

```py
import numba as nb

# Signature of the function (parameter types)
# Note: `::1` means the array is contiguous
@nb.njit('(uint8[::1], uint8[::1], uint8[::1])')
def with_numba(a, b, c):
    seen = dict()

    for va in a:
        for vb in b:
            for vc in c:
                # If the 3 values are different
                if va != vb and vc != vb and vc != va:
                    # Sort the 3 values using a fast sorting network
                    v1, v2, v3 = va, vb, vc
                    if v1 > v2: v1, v2 = v2, v1
                    if v2 > v3: v2, v3 = v3, v2
                    if v1 > v2: v1, v2 = v2, v1

                    # Compact the 3 values into one 32-bit integer
                    packedKey = (np.uint32(v1) << 16) | (np.uint32(v2) << 8) | np.uint32(v3)

                    # Is the sorted tuple (v1,v2,v3) already seen?
                    if packedKey not in seen:
                        # Add the value and remember the ordered tuple (va,vb,vc)
                        packedValue = (np.uint32(va) << 16) | (np.uint32(vb) << 8) | np.uint32(vc)
                        seen[packedKey] = packedValue

    res = np.empty((len(seen), 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i, packed in enumerate(seen.values()):
        res[i, 0] = np.uint8(packed >> 16)
        res[i, 1] = np.uint8(packed >> 8)
        res[i, 2] = np.uint8(packed)

    return res

with_numba(a, b, c)
```

---

### Benchmark

Here are results on my i5-9600KF processor:

```
numpy:                         122.1 ms  (x 1.0)
no_numpy:                       49.6 ms  (x 2.5)
AlainT's solution:              49.0 ms  (x 2.5)
mathfux's solution              34.2 ms  (x 3.5)
mathfux's optimized solution     7.5 ms  (x16.2)
with_numba:                      4.9 ms  (x24.9)
```

The provided solution is about **25 times faster** than the slowest implementation and about **1.5 time faster** than the fastest provided implementation so far.

The current Numba code is bounded by the speed of the Numba dictionary operations. The code can be optimized using more low-level tricks. On solution is to replace the dictionary by a *packed boolean array* (1 item = 1 bit) of size `256**3/8` to track the values already seen (by checking the `packedKey`th bit). The packed values can be directly added in `res` if the fetched bit is not set. This requires `res` to be preallocated to the maximum size or to implement an exponentially growing array (like `list` in Python or `std::vector` in C++). Another optimization is to sort the list and use a *tiling* strategy so to improve *cache locality*. Such optimization are far from being easy to implement but I expect them to drastically speed up the execution.

If you plan to use more arrays, then the hash-map can become a bottleneck and a bit-array can be quite big. While using tiling certainly help to reduce the memory footprint, you can speed up the implementation by a large margin using [Bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). This probabilist data structure can speed up the execution by skipping many duplicates without causing any *cache misses* and with a low memory footprint. You can remove most of the duplicates and then sort the array so to then remove the duplicates. Regarding your problem, a radix sort may be faster than usual sorting algorithms.

Comment: Nice solution and explanation ! It does pretty much the same things as my `numpy` version except that you are using dictionary checks instead of `np.unique` in my version. In the end of my solution I'm offering to use dimensionality reduction (equivalent of compacting 3 values into 32 bit integers your script) to speed up `np.unique` significantly (with x6 performance boost). Did you include it in your measurements?

Comment: Would this solution still be more efficient than the originals with 5 arrays? I would just have to modify the loops/sorting and the packing and unpacking? For 4 arrays the packing would be `packedValue = (np.uint32(va) << 24) | (np.uint32(vb) << 16) | np.uint32(vc) << 8 | np.uint32(vd)` I am unsure how to modify the bit packing to work with 5 or is that not possible?

Comment: I was able to adjust this to work with 4 arrays and it is still much faster than both of my original solutions. For 5 arrays, I have the sorting network for 5 values but I am not sure how to do the bit packing would I need to use a 64 bit integer for 5 values?

Comment: This was the solution I came up with for 5 values `packedKey = (np.uint64(v1) << 32) | (np.uint64(v2) << 24) | np.uint64(v3) << 16 | np.uint64(v4) << 8 | np.uint64(v5)`

Comment: @radio23 Yes it can work efficiently with more arrays. However, you need to use `uint64` variables instead of `uint32` ones (to avoid *overflows*). Additionally, you need to add 2 loops and change the code for the comparison. You can use a sorting network of size 5 (a bit cumber some to write but fast as the compiler can optimize it much more than a basic sort due to the loops). Be aware that the result can be quite big with 5 variables. The hashmap will certainly a problem so implementing the proposed optimisations are certainly quite critical for performance.

Comment: @mathfux Indeed. I included this optimized version I missed. I guess this is nearly optimal for a Numpy code. The implementation is challenging. Good job ;) .

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks. I'm giving three guidelines where to go further in other optimise my code. Majority steps could be rewritten in `numba` but you could also try to optimize reach output of `np.unique` in a different way (it is quite slow method in fact)

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like so:

```
# create full Cartessian product and keep items in sorted form
arr = np.stack(np.meshgrid(a, b, c), axis=-1).reshape(-1, 3)
arr_sort = np.sort(arr, axis=1)

# apply condition 1: no duplicates between sorted items
u, idx_c1 = np.unique(arr_sort, return_index=True, axis=0)
arr_filter, arr_sort_filter = arr[idx_c1], arr_sort[idx_c1]

# apply condition 2: no items with repeated values between sorted items
idx_c2 = (arr_sort_filter[:,0] != arr_sort_filter[:,1]) & \
           (arr_sort_filter[:,1] != arr_sort_filter[:,2])

arr_filter[idx_c2]
>>>
array([[ 1,  2,  0],
       [ 1,  3,  0],
       [ 1,  4,  0],
                ...,
       [75, 71, 74],
       [75, 74, 72],
       [75, 74, 73]], dtype=uint8)
```

It takes 57 ms on my computer vs 77 ms for `no_numpy(args?)` and returns 50014 items.

You could later profile this algorithm in order to see what could be optimised. I do it manually but this would be a great idea to find some profiling tools :)

- arr ~0.2 ms
- arr_sort ~1.4ms
- u, idx_c1 ~ 52ms
- remaining part ~2.5ms

So it's easy too see what consumes all the time here. It could be improved significantly using dimensionality reduction. One of the approaches is to replace

```
u, idx_c1 = np.unique(arr_sort, return_index=True, axis=0)
```

with

```
M = max(np.max(a), np.max(b), np.max(c))
idx = np.ravel_multi_index(arr_sort.T, (M+1, M+1, M+1))
u, idx_c1 = np.unique(idx, return_index=True)
```

It runs only 4.5 ms now and only 9 ms in total! I guess you are capable to speed up this algorithm ~3 times if you optimised these parts:

- use `numba` for faster comparisons in `idx_c2`
- use `numba` to speed up `np.ravel_multi_index` (manual implementation works faster even in `numpy`)
- use `numba` or `numpy` version of `np.bincount` instead of `np.unique`

Comment: Would this solution run into performance issues if the number of arrays grew or the number of items in each of the arrays grew causing more possible combinations?

Comment: `numpy` is not designed for combinatorial problems because ability to perform actions in vectorized way only (no looping) is a limitation sometimes. If you, say, have larger arrays, it's not a problem because runtime grows linearly. But if you try to solve this kind of problem for more arrays, you'll be forced to drop a lot of trash data (might be exponential grow). You might be interested in results of [related case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63694661/3044825).

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be quite hard to get numpy to go as fast as the filtered python iterator because numpy processes whole structures that will inevitably be larger than the result of filtering sets.

Here is the best I could come up with to process the product of arrays in such a way that the result is filtered on unique combinations of distinct values:

```
def npProductSets(a,b,*others):
    if len(a.shape)<2 : a = a[:,None]
    if len(b.shape)<2 : b = b[:,None]
    left  = np.repeat(a,b.shape[0],axis=0)
    right = np.tile(b,(a.shape[0],1))
    distinct = ~np.any(right==left,axis=1)
    prod  = np.concatenate((left[distinct],right[distinct]),axis=1)
    prod.sort(axis=1)
    prod  = np.unique(prod,axis=0) 
    if others:
        return npProductSets(prod,*others)
    return prod
```

This npProductSets function filters the expanded arrays as it goes and does it using numpy methods.  It still runs slower than the Python generators though (0.078 sec vs 0.054 sec).  Numpy is not the ideal tool to combinatorics and set manipulation.

Note that npProductSets returns 50014 items instead of your 58363 because `tuple(set(i))` will not filter all permutations of the numbers.  The conversion of a set to a tuple does not guarantee the order of elements (so duplicate combinations are included in your output because of permuted items).

Comment: What would be the ideal tool for combinatorics and set manipulation performance wise?

Comment: itertools should be good enough but, building your own generator function to implement the filtering would probably give faster results for large lists.  For the uniqueness of combinations I would suggest `frozenset(i)` (which is hashable) instead of `tuple(set(i))`